# WooCommerce account Endpoints changing wp_nav_menu label for different page?

Tags: woocommerce, wp-nav-menu-item

I have an issue with WooCommerce account endpoints changing the navigation label in my primary  wp_nav_menu for a different (unrelated page) page.

Neither the WooCommerce my-account page or it's endpoints are added to the primary wp_nav_menu.

What is a page with the label "Read" changes to "Orders", "Addresses" and so on.

Image for reference: [WooCommerce account endpoints interfering with the navigation label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8BE.png).